# How to know if a specific program is open

Tags: command-line, process, window-management

Using a command line in terminal, I want to be displayed `1` if a program (for example Firefox or Chromium) is open and `0` otherwise.

Edit: By "open", I mean "is running on the current machine and has a window open on the X server that I am seeing"

Comment: By "open", do you mean "is running on the current machine and has a window open on the X server you're seeing", "has a window open on any X server on any machine as any user", "there's a firefox window open which is from a process on any machine connected to the X server you're currently seeing", "has at least one process running that executable on your machine"?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I edited my question with what exactly I mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xwininfo -root -children | grep -q '"Firefox")'
echo "$(($? == 0))"
```

Would output 1 if there's a window of class `Firefox` connected to your X server (by any user from any machine).

To limit to Firefox processes local to the machine where you're running that command:

```
xwininfo -root -children |
  awk '/"Firefox"\)/{print $1}' |
  xargs -I% xprop -id % WM_CLIENT_MACHINE |
  cut -d\" -f2 |
  grep -qFx "$(uname -n)"
```

Searching by process name gives you no guarantee that the processes are actually displaying their window on *your* X server.

The method described above is consistent with how firefox checks for a currently running firefox when not passed the `--no-remote` option.

Answer (score 2):

`pgrep -x chromium` wouldn't match process names like `chromium-foo`, and `> /dev/null` could be replaced with `-q`:

```
pgrep -xq chromium; echo $(($? == 0))
```

`pgrep` is not defined by POSIX, and for example it wasn't included with OS X until recently. But you could also use `ps`:

```
ps -eo comm= | grep -xq chromium; echo $(($? == 0)) # GNU
ps -eco comm= | grep -xq chromium; echo $(($? == 0)) # OS X
ps -eo comm= | sed 's|.*/||' | grep -xq chromium; echo $(($? == 0)) # either
```

In OS X `-o comm` prints the absolute paths of commands and `-co comm` prints basenames. In GNU `-o comm` prints basenames and `-c` is not defined.

Comment: Your commands contains funky options and I'm afraid `echo $?` gives the inverse value of what is asked for.

Comment: @htor, those (except for `-c`) are the standard options as opposed to the BSD-style `aux` `ps` args which should be avoided when seeking portability.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to check if a process having a particular name is currently running. One is to use `pgrep` and another is to use `ps`:

```
pgrep "chromium" >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo 1 || echo 0
ps aux | grep "[c]hromium" >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo 1 || echo 0
grep "[c]hromium" <(ps aux) >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo 1 || echo 0
```

The `pgrep` command looks up processes based on their name and displays the PID of any process that matches its argument. Here the return value of `pgrep` is used instead of its output (hence the redirecting to `/dev/null` ) so we know if something matched or not. The `grep` command will also display matches to `stdout` so it needs to be redirected as well.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Something like `if pgrep chromium &> /dev/null; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi` is doing what I asked... but doesn't exist something more efficient or simple (I prefer just one command)?

Comment: That's nice: `pgrep chromium >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo 1 || echo 0`. Thank you!

Comment: Note that those check for processes by any user whose process name (the first 16 characters of the basename of the first argument of the last execve() system call those processes made on Linux, though processes can also modify it) contains `chromium`. There's no guarantee that those processes are actually connected to your X server.

Comment: my comment above was refering to the `pgrep` solution. For the `ps` one, you're looking for `chromium` any where in the command arguments and username which is even less reliable. You forgot to quote the `[c]` which means the outcome will depend on whether or not there's a file called `chromium` in the current directory.